# how to change the colors of my web page bars based on CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, computer-science, html-helper, helper

Yeah so I am an average 15y/o. I am new to this field and want help , You see I took a template and customized it. The template was from W3 school.com and now I need to change colors of some bars could you mind helping me ? as it would be great help for me!!.The code that I am using is down below;

```
 <p class="w3-large"><b><i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-fw w3-margin-right text-teal"></i>Skills</b></p>
          <p>Adobe Photoshop</p>
          <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="width:90%">90%</div>
          </div>
          
          <p>Illustrator</p>
          <div class="w3-light-black w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="width:75%">75%</div>
          </div>
          <p>Media</p>
          <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="width:50%">50%</div>
          </div>
          <br>

          <p class="w3-large w3-text-theme"><b><i class="fa fa-globe fa-fw w3-margin-right text-teal"></i>Languages</b></p>
          <p>Urdu</p>
          <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
            <div class="w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="height:24px;width:100%"></div>
          </div>
          <p>English</p>
          <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
            <div class="w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="height:24px;width:75%"></div>
          </div>
```

I did try some random things but I failed miserably that is why I need help in changing of the color.!!!

Comment: And what exactly did you try to change the colors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a .css file.
In the css try writhing this:

Write the class name of the object you want to change the color like this:

```
.object 
{  
 background-color: color; 
}
```

This will change the background color but there are many more options.

Comment: thnks it workes